# Cornerstone branching/merging

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I'm currently having problems with the "reintegrate branch" option in cornerstone. I'm getting an error which says "Description 'https://krval22@server.myserver.com/svn/sample/trunk/MyProject@27' must be ancestrally related to 'https://krval22@server.myserver.com/svn/sample/branches/MyProject%201.0@27'".

I'm in a branch "branch/MyProject 1.0" and I'm trying to commit to "trunk/MyProject" by putting it in the "Merge from" field.

If I try to reintegrate it to my main branch, it successfully finishes but it doesn't do anything even after I commit it. The revision number on the main branch isn't reflecting the revision number I'm using even after commit.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my repository structure

branch/MyProject (direct branch from trunk/, not trunk/MyProject)

branch/MyProject 1.0 (branch from branch/MyProject)

trunk/MyProject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `branch/MyProject 1.0` was not copied from `branch/MyProject`.
Or maybe the copy-from information was not recorded for some reason.
Try to run `svn log -v` on `branch/MyProject 1.0` working copy to see if it was really copied from `branch/MyProject`. Maybe it was copied from another place.

Also you can try to merge without merge history: `svn merge --ignore-ancestry`. It may produce conflicts that you'll need to resolve manually.

BTW, I would keep from using of spaces and dots in the folders names. Simply to reduce the risk something will not work because of it.

---

Also see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490164/svn-reintegration-merge-error-must-be-ancestrally-related).

Comment: Fixed. Seems like I was using the wrong directories for checking out. Instead of checking out trunk/ I checked out trunk/MyProject and when attempting to merge, I selected branch/MyProject but there's a subfolder there named MyProject too, so the directories were messed up.

Comment: Had same issue today. Doing it again after selecting the correct sub-directory under the top-level trunk folder fixed it. Thanks for the answer.