# Keep a branch up to date in SVN

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I have a branch on SVN and I'd like to keep it up to date, I am used to git, where I do a merge master into branch and it has all the modifications, so I am asking is it enough to merge just the last revision from trunk into my branch or I shall do a merge of all the revisions? And if this is the case (merge all the revisions) why is it necessary?

Comment: Read the documentation http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync

Comment: but I met a case where a file has changed 2-3 times, and when merging all the revisions, I get into conflicts...

Comment: And it says that first I shall merge my branch into trunk then do the merge from trunk ...

Comment: :| I think the problem is linked somehow to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490164/svn-reintegration-merge-error-must-be-ancestrally-related)